# How to compute the limit: $\lim _{ n\to \infty } \sum _{ r=1 }^{ n }{ \frac { [2rx] }{ { n }^{ 2 } } } $

Tags: limits

How to compute the limit:
$\lim _{ n\to \infty  } \sum _{ r=1 }^{ n }{ \frac { [2rx] }{ { n }^{ 2 } }  } $

I'm trouble in handling the [.] greatest integer function.Help please!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $u-1< \lfloor u\rfloor \le u$ for any $u$. Use this to find upper and lower bounds on the partial sums...